# Using DuckDB with s3?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, duckdb

I'm trying to use DuckDB in a jupyter notebook to access and query some parquet files held in s3, but can't seem to get it to work. Judging on past experience, I feel like I need to assign the appropriate file system but I'm not sure how/where to do that.

The below code raises the error: `RuntimeError: IO Error: No files found that match the pattern "s3://<bucket>/<file>.parquet"`

```
import boto3
import duckdb

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
client=boto3.client("s3")
con = duckdb.connect(database=':memory:', read_only=False)

con.execute("""
SET s3_region='-----';
SET s3_access_key_id='-----';
SET s3_secret_access_key='-----';
""")
out = con.execute(f"select * from parquet_scan('s3://<bucket>/<file>.parquet') limit 10;").fetchall()
```

I'd like to use the pandas `read_sql` functionality if I can, but put this code to avoid adding complexity to the question.

I'm confused because this code works:

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
client=boto3.client("s3")

df = pd.read_parquet("s3://<bucket>/<file>.parquet")
```

Comment: DuckDB appears to not include it's "httpfs" (used for http and s3) [extension on Python](https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/2350).

Comment: anyone looking for GUI tool - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74165348/6563567

Answer (score 8):

Do this instead

```
con.execute("""
INSTALL httpfs;
LOAD httpfs;
SET s3_region='-----';
SET s3_access_key_id='-----';
SET s3_secret_access_key='-----';
""")
```

Answer (score 4):

HTTPFS is not included in the package. However you can build it from source, see the snippet below

This assumes you have python3/pip3 installed on your linux machine or container. I'm using photon4 container, on other linux distros package names might be slightly different.

```
# install build dependencies
yum install build-essential cmake git openssl-devel python3-devel -y

# install python dependencies
pip3 install setuptools numpy

# clone repo with source code
git clone https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb && cd duckdb

# set a flag to build package with HTTPFS
export BUILD_HTTPFS=1
make

# once duckdb libs are built, do it again enabling python package
export BUILD_PYTHON=1
make
```

After that it should be available even without running pip install.
If you building it in separate container, you can copy or replace this file:
`tools/pythonpkg/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/duckdb.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`
to `/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ on your target machine`

Answer (score 3):

```
def query_s3_duckdb(bucket_name, object_name):
    try:
        # Connect to DuckDB and load Parquet file
        conn = duckdb.connect()
        conn.execute("INSTALL httpfs")
        conn.execute("LOAD httpfs")
        conn.execute("SET s3_region='us-east-1'")
        conn.execute("SET s3_access_key_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'")
        conn.execute("SET s3_secret_access_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'")
        conn.execute(f"CREATE TABLE data AS SELECT * FROM read_parquet('s3://{bucket_name}/{object_name}')")

        # Query data
        result = conn.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data")
        print(f"Number of rows in data: {result.fetchone()[0]}")

        # Cleanup
        conn.close()
    except S3Error as e:
        print(f"Error querying data from S3: {e}")
```

This should work!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for the answer. The docs are here: https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/import/s3_import.html. 

Is it necessary to install httpfs at every query?