# Why won't this duckdb query of s3/parquet data save 'EXPLAIN ANALYZE' profiling info?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, profiling, duckdb

(UPDATED 3/10)

Based on [this duckdb docs page on profiling](https://duckdb.org/dev/profiling), I would have thought that my code snippet below should save a json file of profiling/timing stats to a `query_profile.json`, which I should be able to use to generate an html file with `python -m duckdb.query_graph query_profile.json`

However, my code below (reproducable as it just hits a public s3 bucket, though you'll need your own aws creds in your own .env file) does not produce such a `query_profile.json` file:

```
import duckdb
import s3fs
from dotenv import dotenv_values

# load environment variables from .env file
ENV = dotenv_values(".env")

# Configurable query params
TAXI_COLOR = "yellow"
YEAR = 2023
PROFILE = True

# where to save result (data) locally
dbfile = 'taxi_data.duckdb'

# where to save profiling results
profile_file = 'query_profile.json'

# Define the S3 glob pattern to match the desired parquet files
s3_glob_path = f"s3://nyc-tlc/trip data/{TAXI_COLOR}_tripdata_{YEAR}*.parquet"

# query the s3 parquet data using duckdb
with duckdb.connect(database=dbfile) as con:
    
    # load extension required for reading from s3
    con.execute("INSTALL 'httpfs';")
    con.execute("LOAD 'httpfs';")

    # Set the AWS credentials to access the S3 bucket
    con.execute("SET s3_region='us-east-1';")
    con.execute(f"SET s3_access_key_id = '{ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']}';")  
    con.execute(f"SET s3_secret_access_key = '{ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']}';")  

    # Enable profiling and save the profiling results directly to a file
    con.execute(f"SET profiling_output='{profile_file}'")
    con.execute("SET profiling_mode='detailed'")

    # Execute the query to load and save the data directly to the specified DuckDB file
    tablename = f'{TAXI_COLOR}_tripdata_{YEAR}'
    ea = "EXPLAIN ANALYZE " if PROFILE else ""
    query = f"""{ea}CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE {tablename} AS
                SELECT * FROM read_parquet(['{s3_glob_path}'])
            """
    print(query)
    con.execute(query)

print(f"Data saved to {dbfile} as {tablename}")
print(f"Profiling results saved to {profile_file}")
```

Comment: I'd be suspicious of the wildcard in `{TAXI_COLOR}_tripdata_{YEAR}-*.parquet` -- unless DuckDB is very clever and knows how to list files in S3 before reading files, I'd say that the wildcard won't work. Instead, try referring the Prefix alone: `{TAXI_COLOR}_tripdata_{YEAR}-` Also, I couldn't see the square bracket being used in [S3 Parquet Import - DuckDB](https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/import/s3_import.html), so perhaps leave it out? Failing that, it would appear that you can't point DuckDB to a directory or Prefix, since the documentation example specifically points to a filename.

Comment: hey thanks for the comment, though the duckdb docs (I'm linking 0.9 docs since that's my library version) on globbing multiple files is here: https://duckdb.org/docs/archive/0.9/data/multiple_files/overview .

Comment: I managed to reproduce your error, even when pointing to a specific file. Strangely, it says `HTTP Error: HTTP GET error on 'https://nyc-tlc.s3.amazonaws.com/trip%20data/yellow_tripdata_2023-01.parquet' (HTTP 400)` -- It's getting a permission error, apparently because it isn't passing credentials with the request. This was also interesting: [mongodb - Is there a tool to query Parquet files which are hosted in S3 storage? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74136530/is-there-a-tool-to-query-parquet-files-which-are-hosted-in-s3-storage/74165348#74165348)

Comment: hey we're making progress. replacing `con.execute("SET s3_region='auto';")` with `con.execute("SET s3_region='us-east-1';")` proceeds me to a new error which looks like a much simpler issue (though I think I still have a thornier EXPLAIN ANALYZE bug hidden behind that). I'm a little confused since `aws configure get region` says `us-east-1` is the region my account/creds is associated with my default, but maybe I'm misinterpreting that...

Comment: ...yeah confirmed; so now my only outstanding issue is the one I was trying to reproduce in the first place - why I'm not getting any profiling json output saved. will update my question accordingly.

Comment: Great! Credentials can be used with _any_ region, so it's probably improving things by pointing to the same region as the Bucket. If you remove the Profiling part, does the code work? For example, just doing a SELECT or just an EXPLAIN?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257125/discussion-between-max-power-and-john-rotenstein).

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that when you run

```
con.execute(f"SET profiling_output='{profile_file}'")
con.execute("SET profiling_mode='detailed'")
```

DuckDB will output the profiling information for `SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE` statements into the file. If you run an `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` query, the profiling information will not be written to the desired file, but will rather show up in the result. If you run a straight `SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE` query, then the profiling information is written to the file. and the result is the result of the query.

Let me know if that helps.