Issue with parsed values from long lists of structs in Polars
I'm running into what seems like an inference issue. If I have a list of structs (made up of fields of 4 different data types), polars will only parse fields if a value appears within the first 25 items of the list.
I'm loading json data into a frame (passing through json.loads first to convert to dict). The data is heavily nested.
The problem is, there is a column that is a list of structs. I'm passing a pre-defined schema to the DataFrame class on load. So the field in question looks like this:
{
"attributes": pl.List(pl.Struct({
  "stringValue": pl.String,
  "boolValue": pl.Boolean,
  "intValue": pl.Int64,
  "doubleValue": pl.Float64
}))}

Only 1 value type appears per item in the list. As an example, if string and bool types appear in the first 25 items, they will parse correctly in the rest of the items. If, for instance, int types appear after item 25, it will return as None.
Is this expected behavior?
Is there any way to configure the number of items that are inferred?
Is there a work around?
I've tried various schema definitions, infer_schema_length , using read_json vs pl.DataFrame. If I use test data and manipulate the order of the items in the list, I can get it to work. The problem is that I have no control of the order of items in the list field.
UPDATE
Example:
import polars as pl

data_schema = {
    "attributes": pl.List(pl.Struct({
        "key": pl.String,
        "value": pl.Struct({
            "stringValue": pl.String,
            "doubleValue": pl.Float64,
            "boolValue": pl.Boolean,
            "intValue": pl.Int64,
        }),
    })),
}

data = [
    {
        "attributes": [
            {"key": "string1", "value": {"stringValue": "sv1"}},
            {"key": "string2", "value": {"stringValue": "sv2"}},
            {"key": "string3", "value": {"stringValue": "sv3"}},
            {"key": "string4", "value": {"stringValue": "sv4"}},
            {"key": "string5", "value": {"stringValue": "sv5"}},
            {"key": "string6", "value": {"stringValue": "sv6"}},
            {"key": "string7", "value": {"stringValue": "sv7"}},
            {"key": "string8", "value": {"stringValue": "sv8"}},
            {"key": "string9", "value": {"stringValue": "sv9"}},
            {"key": "int1", "value": {"intValue": 1}},
            {"key": "int2", "value": {"intValue": 2}},
            {"key": "int3", "value": {"intValue": 3}},
            {"key": "string10", "value": {"stringValue": "sv10"}},
            {"key": "string11", "value": {"stringValue": "sv11"}},
            {"key": "string12", "value": {"stringValue": "sv12"}},
            {"key": "string13", "value": {"stringValue": "sv13"}},
            {"key": "string14", "value": {"stringValue": "sv14"}},
            {"key": "string15", "value": {"stringValue": "sv15"}},
            {"key": "string16", "value": {"stringValue": "sv16"}},
            {"key": "string17", "value": {"stringValue": "sv17"}},
            {"key": "string18", "value": {"stringValue": "sv18"}},
            {"key": "string19", "value": {"stringValue": "sv19"}},
            {"key": "string20", "value": {"stringValue": "sv20"}},
            {"key": "string21", "value": {"stringValue": "sv21"}},
            {"key": "string22", "value": {"stringValue": "sv22"}},
            {"key": "string23", "value": {"stringValue": "sv23"}},
            {"key": "string24", "value": {"stringValue": "sv24"}},
            {"key": "string25", "value": {"stringValue": "sv25"}},
            {"key": "int4", "value": {"intValue": 4}},
            {"key": "int5", "value": {"intValue": 5}},
            {"key": "bool1", "value": {"boolValue": True}},
            {"key": "bool2", "value": {"boolValue": False}},
            {"key": "bool3", "value": {"boolValue": True}},
            {"key": "double1", "value": {"doubleValue": 0.1}},
            {"key": "double2", "value": {"doubleValue": 2.3}},
        ]
    }
]

df = pl.DataFrame(data, schema=data_schema)

df.rows()

output:
[([{'key': 'string1',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv1',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string2',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv2',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string3',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv3',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string4',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv4',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string5',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv5',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string6',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv6',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string7',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv7',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string8',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv8',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string9',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv9',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'int1',
    'value': {'stringValue': None,
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': 1}},
   {'key': 'int2',
    'value': {'stringValue': None,
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': 2}},
   {'key': 'int3',
    'value': {'stringValue': None,
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': 3}},
   {'key': 'string10',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv10',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string11',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv11',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string12',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv12',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string13',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv13',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string14',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv14',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string15',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv15',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string16',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv16',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string17',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv17',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string18',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv18',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string19',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv19',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string20',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv20',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string21',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv21',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string22',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv22',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string23',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv23',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string24',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv24',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'string25',
    'value': {'stringValue': 'sv25',
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'int4',
    'value': {'stringValue': None,
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': 4}},
   {'key': 'int5',
    'value': {'stringValue': None,
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': 5}},
   {'key': 'bool1',
    'value': {'stringValue': None,
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'bool2',
    'value': {'stringValue': None,
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'bool3',
    'value': {'stringValue': None,
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'double1',
    'value': {'stringValue': None,
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}},
   {'key': 'double2',
    'value': {'stringValue': None,
     'doubleValue': None,
     'boolValue': None,
     'intValue': None}}],)]


Could you provide a concrete example to make the issue reproducible?

Added example in post

Does it happen with the raw json? e.g. pl.read_json(json.dumps(data).encode()) (or with also passing schema= if your real data is too big for default inference)

@jqurious I get an error when I try read_json (obviously I'm working with much larger/wider files):
PanicException: called Option::unwrap() on a None value

Ouch. If you are able to make a reproducible example with fake data - consider filing a bug. The DataFrame() issue seems to be a variation of https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/15327#issuecomment-2022905745 - although in this case, it is much more serious as you are providing the schema. This is definitely not expected behaviour and should also be reported if possible.

Perhaps you could try creating a Polars DataFrame via duckdb e.g. duckdb.sql("from 'file.json'").pl() to see if that also has errors.

Oo. That's a good suggestion. Do you have an example to read from S3? I'm using s3fs. I'm just not as familiar with duckdb's syntax for remote connections

I think you can just do from 's3://...' but it's not something I've used: https://duckdb.org/docs/extensions/httpfs/s3api.html

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69801372/using-duckdb-with-s3

If I take your data and then save it to a json file then polars seems to properly infer all the fields using pl.read_json even if I don't explicitly set the schema
To be clear I'm doing
with open('blah.json','w') as ff:
    ff.write(json.dumps(data))
df=pl.read_json("blah.json")

To confirm it's not ignoring anything I just do
(
    df
    .explode('attributes')
    .unnest('attributes')
    .unnest('value')
    .filter(pl.all_horizontal(pl.exclude('key').is_null()))
)

the filter returns any row where at least one of the values is null. It returns nothing so that means it's working.
I ran into same issue when using the pl.DataFrame constructor. That is a bug but if your ultimate source is a json file anyway then using the polars method would be better even if this bug didn't exist.

I initially tried the read_json method, but ran into issues which is why I switched to pl.DataFrame(json.loads(file)). I'll see if I can get the read_json method to read correctly

I get this error when I try read_json:
PanicException: called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value


What polars version?

Another thought...maybe your source json file is malformed such that json.loads can cope but pl.read_json can't. You could try loading with json.loads and then resaving with json.dumps and then try again with pl.read_json. As an aside orjson is much faster than the standard json in the standard python library. If that works you could diff the two json files, find the difference and put a feature request in with that example to make the polars json parser resilient to whatever the defect is.

polars 0.20.16. I was playing around with the file yesterday.  If I read directly from local file, it works. If I read from a file object, like StringIO or s3fs.open() it fails. I ended up doing the suggestion above of using duckdb. It should improve performance too, which is a happy side effect. I'll write up what I did when I get a moment and submit a bug to the Polars team on the file object read

Don't use StringIO, use BytesIO and when you so s3fs.open() do s3fs.open(filepath, "rb")
